# Angular - Form. Submit button is getting enabled only after user clicks outside the input or tab out

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Angular - Form. Submit button is getting enabled only after user clicks outside the input or tab out. Submit button should enable once a valid change is made.

Tried adding a property to enable and disable the Submit button. But it does not help.

Comment: Providing code is essential to receive proper help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need something like this with ReactiveForm module, is called update strategy in `AbstractControlOptions` and can be applied to formControl and FormGroup, in your case use `'change'`

```
signUpFormGroup = new FormGroup(
  {
    fullName: new FormControl('', {
      updateOn: 'blur'
    }),
    email: new FormControl('')
  },
  { updateOn: 'submit' } // updateOn can be 'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'
);
```